# EF Code First deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have an MVC code-first application that creates a database based on my schema. On the production machine, we will need to first create the database (empty, with no tables), so that we can assign the proper username and password to my dbcontext in the connection string. Considering that the DB is created on production, what should my code do?

I can't use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges because a DB will already be created with no Metadata.. and can't use DropCreateDatabaseAlways because I need it created only the first time.

I also tried this:

```
 if (context.Database.Exists() && !context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
                context.Database.Delete();

            if (context.Database.CreateIfNotExists())
```

but context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false) return always TRUE on an empty database for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

You might need to deploy the database schema via SQL script manually.  You can generate the script from your production database instance.